# Hibernate: avoid implicit initialization of a collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections, jackson

We're using entity classes for two purposes:

1. As a database model, i.e. Hibernate `@Entity`
2. As a data model sent over to the front end as JSON

Imagine an `@Entity` has a number of bulky collections, e.g.:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Order> orders;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Counterparty> counterparties;

    /* ... a lot of other properties, including collections ... */

}
```

Now, we work with `Customer` in two major ways:

1. Fetch an individual customer for viewing/editing, complete with all collections.
2. Fetch a list of customers, with just their "core" properties required for display; we don't need any of its child collections loaded as we're not using them and they generate a lot of additional queries.

My preferred solution would be *explicit* initialization of collections for the case **1**, and keeping them `null` or empty for the case **2**.

The problem is that when Jackson serializes an object into JSON, it goes over all  properties, including collection ones, so they are forced to be initialized. Adding `@JsonIgnore` is not an option (we need those collections for case **1**), adding `@Transient` to keep Hibernate away from them is not an option either (we have to be able to store collections after editing).

Another alternative would be, of course, creating a different model of `Customer` without collections and using that for scenario **2**, but that means maintaining two varieties of the same entity and I'd like to avoid that.

How can I disable Hibernate's implicitly loading of these collections, so that they are only initialized explicitly (via e.g. `Hibernate.initialize(customer.orders)`), while retaining the possibility of persisting them when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I've solved it in the "DTO-fashion" but with minimal overhead, by adding an alternative getter for each property, like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Order> orders;

    /* "Normal" getter to be used in the back-end */ 
    @JsonIgnore // <-- Important as it hides it from Jackson
    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    /* Non-initializing getter for serialization for the front-end */ 
    public List<Order> getOrdersNonInit() {
        return Hibernate.isInitialized(orders) ? orders : null;
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it in Hibernate.

Alternatives:

1. Use DTOs. This has the advantage of tailoring the objects to be serialized to the exact needs of the client consuming the resulting JSON. Also, the domain model (Hibernate entities) is decoupled from the serialization logic, allowing the two to evolve independently.
2. Use [custom serializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers).

Answer (score 0):

The following is just one possible solution and depends on your environment.

There's a project called "jackson-datatype-hibernate" from the FasterXML project. You can find it at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate which allows to define a custom serializer with includes disabling of lazy fields.  (I think this default for this serializer).

Code could look like the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Hibernate4Module hibernateModule = new Hibernate4Module();
mapper.registerModule(hibernateModule);
```

Comment: Might be a good way to solve the problem, but it's really really hard to understand how to use it, with no documentation or examples whatsoever and pretty scarce Javadocs. In the end I gave up on it and created alternative non-initializing getters.

Comment: This code is everything you need beside the dependency which is linked. Just serialize the object with this mapper. The default behaviour of this should be that lazy collections are not serialized.